# After a clean installation GUI not working-AMD GPU

Tags: kali-linux, gui, init, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

- Kali version 2016.2 64bit full version
- Kali installation: main os-SSD
- **An error message:** [ 2.691529] radeon 0000:01:00.0 VCE init error (-22).
- Solutions tried and their result:

> gdm3 / X

also

```
    apt-get update
    apt-get upgrade -y    
    apt-get install -f gdm3
```

Noting worked, also tried more soultions in the web..

The Grapical intall work fine, but when the system come up its stayed just text. And I have to move to tty2..

Specs:
AMD Radeon™ R5 M430 and Intel grapichs HD 620.

Tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/850627/kali-linux-wont-boot-from-gui), not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to reinstall windows but this time using UEFI.
And then using the kali installation with UEFI or Lagacy mode.
That solved my problem..